# Google App Script - Fetch address unavailable when run as a trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have written a google script to get client phone numbers in from the Pipeline Deals api: https://api.pipelinedeals.com/api/v3/people.json?attrs=total&search_id=SEARCH_ID&api_key=API_KEY

It runs fine if I manually run the function, however if I set it up as a time based trigger it returns 'address unavaliable' and errors the script.

```
// Fetch url data and return parsed JSON or false
function getJSON(object, params){
  try {
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch( getUrl(object, params), {method: "GET"} );
    if( !serverResponse(res) ){
      return false;
    }
    return JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  } catch(e) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(EMAIL, 'Google App Scripts: Get JSON Error', e+'<br/>'+getUrl(object, params) );
  }
}
```

I have posted above the part of the code that is causing the error, does anyone know if there is a way to make this work?

Comment: You'll probably need to log some data, and try to figure out what is going on.  Log the contents of `object` and `params` to a spreadsheet, both running it manually, and with a trigger.   `var objStr = JSON.stringify(object); SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID of Sheet File to LOG to').getSheetByName('Put sheet name here').appendRow([objStr]);`